# How to write on delete cascade in wordpress, while creating plugin

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I want to write on delete cascade and on update cascade while creating database in my WordPress plugin

```
public function create_table(){
    global $wpdb;

    require_once (ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

    $ps_detail_table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'ps_details';
    $ps_category_table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'ps_category';
    $ps_type_table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'ps_type';

    $ps_detail_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$ps_detail_table_name."(
                      id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      category VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                      type VARCHAR(255) NULL,
                      image_path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                      name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                      description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                      PRIMARY KEY (id),
                      FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES ".$ps_type_table_name."(type)
                      ON DELETE CASCADE
                      ON UPDATE CASCADE 
                      )";
    dbDelta($ps_detail_sql);

    $ps_category_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$ps_category_table_name."(
                      id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      category VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                      PRIMARY KEY (id))";
    dbDelta($ps_category_sql);

    $ps_type_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$ps_type_table_name."(
                      id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      category VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                      type VARCHAR(255) NULL,
                      PRIMARY KEY (id))";
    dbDelta($ps_type_sql);

}
```

This is my code it'll work if I remove ON DELETE CASCADE AND ON UPDATE CASCADE if it there then other two table creates except that table that includes CASCADE. what should I do for this problem?